# Can't get Youtube mediaelement embed working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, youtube, mediaelement.js

I am using mediaelement player in my WordPress plugin.

In Internet explorer, embedding youtube inside an iframe not working whereas it works inside Chrome and Firefox.

In Internet explorer it shows the blank screen

While inspecting with the help of developers tool I see that iframe tag is not loading at all. Here is the screenshot:
[image: Internet Explorer Debugger]

In chrome,  tag is getting loaded

[image: Chrome Developer tools]

Please, can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Checked the console for errors? Plus, you’re emulating IE 9 here according to your screenshot - have you checked whether this is even supposed to work in that more than outdated browser ...?

Comment: @CBroe There are ni console errors and same results while emulating it using IE11

Answer (score 1):

If it doesent work in IE9 best option is to fall back to flash. You can do this two ways;

The hacky way adding a meta tag to render as IE8 hence faling back to flash;

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

The better way is to set in the wordpress options 'mode: 'auto_plugin' - which should force IE 9 to use flash.

Comment: Black screen is getting displayed even in IE11. Please can you tell me the exact option name as I can not find the option:mode inside the wp_options table

Comment: adding mode:'auto-plugin' into the mediaelement options resolves an IE issue. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: this solution doesn't work now, I don't know how I concluded other day?